# When to use else if instead of if?

Tags: c++, if-statement

Suppose we have this code:

```
if (condition_1)
   do this
if (condition_2)
   do that
else
   do blablabla
```

And now this one:

```
if (condition_1)
   do this
else if (condition_2)
   do that
else
   do blablabla
```

And now let's check what happens line by line. If i'm not mistaken, the first program starts checking if condition_1 is true or false, then the same thing happens for condition_2. And if none of these conditions are true, the program runs "do blablabla".

The second program starts from checking condition_1, and if it's false then if checks condition_2. If condition_2 if false, if does nothing (by nothing i mean it ignores the else statement).
If so, the second if statment from the second program can be replaced by:

```
if (!(condition_1) and condition_2)
   do that
```

But else then can be run, i thought that every else if statement can be replaced by only if with a bit longer condition. So is this possible to replace every else if by using only if? And when "do blablabla"  will run?

Comment: The second fragment does run `do blablabla` if neither `condition_1` nor `condition_2` holds.

Comment: Your interpretation of your examples is wrong. In your first example, if `condition_1 == true`, and `condition_2 == false`, `this` and `blablabla` will both be executed.

Comment: Yes, a programming language that has `if` but not `else` would still be Turing-complete - just less readable. It is indeed possible, in principle, to transform any C++ program into an equivalent program that doesn't use `else`.

Comment: Note: the `else` is only attached to the last `if`.

Comment: Look at your first example --  `if (condition_1) do this` -- What happens inside "do this"?  What if the stuff inside "do this" affects the `if (condition_2)` test?  Now look at the second example -- regardless of what "do this" does, it will never get to the `if (condition_2)` test, all due to the `else`.

Comment: When you need `else` you will know it.

Comment: I also believe the OP is overthinking the issue.  If the logic requires `else if`, then use `else if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First part:

```
 if (condition_1)
       do this

// previous if has nothing to do with this if & else 

if (condition_2)
   do that
else
   do blablabla
```

This case if `condition_2` is true then `do that` will be executed, otherwise `do blablabla`
will be executed..

Now the second part:

```
if (condition_1)
   do this
else if (condition_2)
   do that
else
   do blablabla
```

Here, the *first* true condition will be executing and rest of `else if` & `else` will be ignored, all conditions will be checked sequentially till `else` or a `true` condition is found.
If no conditions hold then `else` will be executed. So `do blablabla` will be executed if those **both** of two conditions are `false`

And finally, yes second `if` can be replaced by:

```
if (!(condition_1) and condition_2)
   do that
```

This is because second if will be checked (`do that` will be executed) only if the `condition_1` is false.. and `condition_2` is true.

Which is equivalent to: (if and only if the `condition_1` is `false`)

```
if (!(false) and condition_2)
       do that
```

You can replace else `if`s by checking whether previous condition was false, this way each `else if`s with previous conditions, this is tedious.

Example:

```
if (a) {
    // do task1
} else if (b) {
    // do task2
} else if (c) {
    // do task3
} else {
    // do task4
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if (a) {
    // do task1
}
if (!a and b) {
    // do task2
}
if (!a and !b and c) {
    // do task3
}
if (!a and !b and !c) {
   // here is the else
   // do task4
}
```

> When to use else if instead of if?

Generally speaking, we chain `if`, else if's and an `else` at the last to ensure execution of **only** one condition, if one is `true` rest are ignored and executions goes to the next of very last line ( `}` ) of last `else`.

Answer (score 1):

> If i'm not mistaken, the first program starts checking if condition_1 is true or false, then the same thing happens for condition_2. And if none of these conditions are true, the program runs "do blablabla".

No, `condition_1` does not influence what happens in `condition_2`. `condition_1` can be either `true` or `false` but it's only `condition_2` that matters in the second condition:

```
if (condition_1) {
   do this
}

// --- no connection here ---

if (condition_2) {
   do that
} else {
   do blablabla
}
```

It's different in the second version since then `condition_1` must be `false` for `condition_2` to be even evaluated. It helps to put curly brackets out:

```
if (condition_1) {
    do this
} else {
    if (condition_2) {
        do that
    } else {
        do blablabla
    }
}
```